# Concurrent Workflows - Item changed by workflow(2) during lifecycle of workflow(1)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow

SP 2013
Teamsite-Template

I got 2 lists in my Teamsite. When an item was created or changed on list A a WF starts and the Item is copied to list B (create or update if exist). On list B there is another WF running that automatically approves the item after setting permissions properly. So far so good.

Now I ran into a (seldom) problem. Here is what is happening:

1. Item was created on list A.
2. List A WF creates item on list B.
3. List B WF starts running on this new item BUT is delayed!
4. Shortly after creation the item was changed again on list A.
5. List A WF updates the item on list B (while delayed WF has not yet finished)!
6. Another instance of list B WF starts.
7. Both instances of list B WFs finish.

It seems as if it is possible one WF is delayed and that another WF (that was started later on another list) can finish fist. So it is not clear that the WF that started first will finish first?

It this true? I need to somehow maintain the state of the related item during a WF lifetime even if another WF will change this item in the meantime.

Thank you!

Comment: In your situation what would happen ideally? Do you want the second workflow to not run a second time?

Comment: Ideally it should be possible to put the workflows in order. In my case it could be that when WF1 starts a boolean field in the related item is TRUE but then the WF2 starts and changes this value to FALSE (while WF1 was delayed). As this is an e-mail option WF1 does not send any mail.

Answer (score 1):

My personal preference would be to substitute both workflows with a single, synchronous event handler in List A, which will take care of the original item and the copied item in List B.

Comment: True, but this includes coding. Sadly it seems as if there is no OOTB solution to this Problem. Only a workaround that I described.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could put some client side code (js) in the editpage that checks (via ajax rest call) for the approval status of the correspondibg item in the related list. You could disable the save buttons or show a message etc..